# Recordset with few results causing 'Overflow' error

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

When a particular form loads I need to grab a distinct list of locations from a table, with the eventual goal of displaying them to the user (baby steps though, I'll get to that).

The code below generates no error, but when I try to loop through the recordset returned by my query, I get an error in relation to the integer `i`.

> Run-time error '6': Overflow

I've tested the query and it does return the results that I expect, so I believe that my handling of the `Recordset` object my be the issue.

what am I doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub Form_load()

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Set DB = CurrentDb  ' Set the DB object to use

    '**
     ' Grab a recordset containing distinct locations
     '*
    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT [Active Directory].[AD Location] FROM [Active Directory]" _
    )

    Dim i As Integer: i = 0
    Dim locations() As String
    ReDim locations(0)

    '**
     ' Make an array of the locations to display
     '*
    If Not (RS.EOF And RS.BOF) Then ' Ensure that the recordset is not empty

        RS.MoveFirst    ' Move to the first record (unnecessary here, but good practice)

        '**
         ' Loop through the recordset and extract the locations
         '*
        Do Until RS.EOF = True

            locations(i) = RS![AD Location]
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve locations(i)

        Loop

    Else

        '**
         ' Tell the user that there are no records to display
         '*
        Call MsgBox( _
            "Sorry, something went wrong and there are no locations to display." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Please ensure that the Active Directory table is not empty.", _
            vbExclamation, _
            "You'd better sit down, it's not good news..." _
        )

    End If

    RS.Close            ' Close the recordset
    Set RS = Nothing    ' Be a hero and destroy the now defunct record set

End Sub
```

Comment: You miss recordset movenext inside loop :)

Comment: Of course! I'm so used to using `for each` loops that I forgot to move to the next record. D'oh!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not missing something, you could just use *GetRows*:

```
Dim locations As Variant
RS.MoveLast
i = RS.RecordCount
RS.MoveFirst
locations = RS.GetRows(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Arvo who commented that I had forgotten to move to the next record in my `do` loop.

Adding `RS.MoveNext` to the loop fixed the problem.

```
Do Until RS.EOF = True

    locations(i) = RS![AD Location]
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve locations(i)
    RS.MoveNext

Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know what you are doing so my question is probably pointless as I'm sure you have a good reason, BUT... why are you stuffing the recordset values into an Array?... Or more specifically how are you displaying the results to the user in the end?

I ask because it would seem to be much simpler to just bind your SQL statement into a control (subform, combobox, listbox etc.) rather than iterating through records like your doing. But, as I said I imagine you have your reasons for doing it that way.